# enabling foreground mode on NFC could cause draining the battery?

Tags: android, nfc

Quoting Carl Sagan:

> There are naive questions, tedious questions, ill-phrased questions, questions put after inadequate self-criticism. But every question is a cry to understand the world. There is no such thing as a dumb question.

because I think this is a really stupid question, but I just want to solve my doubt.

I'm working in an app with NFC and I'd like to enable the foreground mode forever to be able to handle a new intent even when the app gets killed.

So, let's imagine that the NFC is always ON. Will my feature drain the battery, or consume it faster that if I disable eventually the foreground mode?

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Rafael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wont drain your battery much. There are two different modes. In passive mode, there is no energy consumed by the device since it is being read. In active mode, there is a small amount of current (less than 15 mA) that will be used.

Since NFC uses 13.56MHz and is short range, very negligible power is consumed. I had conducted a test for NFC ON always and had kept the phone in airplane mode(all network and other wireless modes OFF except NFC) and found out that the phone battery drained out in a normal way like 1 week. Hence no problem.